# How to select filed array to show in one row or show json in one row

Tags: php, mysql

```
select 
       s.id,
       s.name,
       c.PNAME city,
       s.user_name,
       s.logo,
       sqrt(pow((latitude-'1'),2)+pow((longitude-'1'),2)) as distance ,
       (SELECT 
              ph.phone_number 
        FROM `phones` as ph 
        WHERE (ph.type='tel' AND ph.`shop_id`=s.id)) as phons
from shops as s
JOIN addresses  as a ON s.address_id=a.id 
JOIN city as c ON c.id=a.city
where 1
order by('distance ASC')
limit 0,20 ;
```

Above `code` give me an `error` :

> Error code 1242, SQL state 21000: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: do we have a question here?

Comment: use json_encode($result_here) to convert into json.

Comment: please explain more !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select s.id,s.name,
c.PNAME city,s.user_name,s.logo,
sqrt(pow((latitude-'1'),2)+pow((longitude-'1'),2)) as distance ,
((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ph.phone_number) FROM `phones` as ph WHERE (ph.type='tel'))) as phons
from shops as s
 JOIN addresses  as a ON s.address_id=a.id 
JOIN city as c ON c.id=a.city
where 1
order by('distance ASC')
limit 0,20 ;

GROUP_CONCAT reult numberphone in row
```

Answer (score 1):

use `limit 1` in sub query like

```
SELECT ph.phone_number FROM `phones` as ph 
        WHERE (ph.type='tel' AND ph.`shop_id`=s.id limit 1
```